# Neo4j algo.shortestPath with only certain label of relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

I am new to Neo4j and I am trying to figure out how to use a few basic path finding algorithms. Essentially, I have a collection of notes labelled `LogisticalUnit`, representing companies or locations that can ship goods to other places. Two such units can have a relationship `SHIPS_TO` with a property `cost`. Attempting to find a path with minimal cost to go from node `A` to `B` gives me a promising result using `algo.shortestPath.stream`:

```
match (startNode :LogisticalUnit {id: 2}), (endNode :LogisticalUnit {id: 5})
call algo.shortestPath.stream(startNode, endNode, 'cost', {direction: 'OUTGOING', nodeQuery: 'LogisticalUnit', relationshipQuery: 'SHIPS_TO'})
yield nodeId, cost
return *;
```

However, it turns out that if I have another relationship such as `RECOMMENDS`, and it has the `cost` property, it is considered as well. It seems the `relationshipQuery` config does not actually work. As a matter of fact, replacing the config with `relationshipQuery: 'FOOBAR'`, while no such relationship even exists in my database, will still return the same result!

The `nodeQuery` property behaves as expected and if I change it to another label it will correctly dismiss the results.

Any idea where I'm going wrong here? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It is behaving as if you misspelled "relationshipQuery", but as far as I can tell, you spelled it correctly. I can't test if this is a bug. Is the Cypher you posted a direct copy-paste of what you executed?

Comment: I did notice it's possible to add random configs and Cypher won't complain, so I considered it could have been a typo. I made sure to copypaste the name from the documentation. The Cypher query I posted is a direct copy-paste with only a change in the name of the node label and addition of newlines.